# How to identify OCaml extensible variant type value in C?

Tags: c, ocaml, variant

I have an OCaml library and want to use it in C. This library has an error management system based on extensible variants. [Chapter 20 Interfacing C with OCaml](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#ss:c-concrete-datatypes) contains a description of how to identify variant type value in C (it dependent on constructors order).

> The following example illustrates the assignment of integers and block
> tags to constructors:
>
> ```ml
> type t =
>   | A             (* First constant constructor -> integer "Val_int(0)" *)
>   | B of string   (* First non-constant constructor -> block with tag 0 *)
>   | C             (* Second constant constructor -> integer "Val_int(1)" *)
>   | D of bool     (* Second non-constant constructor -> block with tag 1 *)
>   | E of t * t    (* Third non-constant constructor -> block with tag 2 *)
> ```

How to identify [**extensible** variant type](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extensiblevariants.html) value in C?